# How to scroll down and up on dynamic view port

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to make a responsive page with two part at [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/aLvEr/) as:

1. Map View
2. Table View

Both views (table and Map divs must be responsive - with not hard coded height) so the map div size will be adjusted automatically from the viewport. As you can see, I made it hard coded. How can I fix it?

There are also two buttons controls as `"gomap"` and `"gotable"` which I am able to position the gomap on the second div (table) but not success on adding the first control.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
   <div id="map"></div>
   <div id="table"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/aLvEr/2/)? Setting `position:absolute` allows you to set height to a percentage. And your button didnt fade in because the `scrollTo` was set to fadein at the same time the other button did.